# Need to convert DFF(old access file) to SQL or access file

Tags: conversion

I have DDF (old Access file) files that I need to convert to SQL file or Access file.

Does anyone know which program I can use?

"MDB Admin" & "Stellar Repair for Access" does not do the work (foreign language comes gibberish).

"mdbtools" - takes too much work.

Windows system, prefers free tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Access produced these file Size?

Comment: Hi @DanielK , 
What version of Access produced? no idea something like 20 years ago
these file Size? 40MB .   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Searching on internet i found the following information, seems to be adjusted to your needs:

https://www.goldstarsoftware.com/ddf-building.asp

One important issue according my searchings is to realize which software uses ddf files for previous sql conversion.

Comment: This is a broken link. The right link is: http://www.goldstarsoftware.com/ddf-building.asp